# Bootstrap collapsed navbar disappears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on the toggle on my mobile page, the menu pops up for a brief moment and disappears again. Only the first item remains visible.

I took the css from [thebootstrapthemes](http://thebootstrapthemes.com/premium-bootstrap-agency-template/) and basically just changed the colors and the content of the menu.

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="top-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="#"></a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse  collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pronunciation.html">Pronunciation</a></li>
            <li><a href="/downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any advice, how I can get my menu back?

This is my [site](http://www.learnchinesein100days.com/)

Comment: Tested and it's working fine :) Fiddle please?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it here, my first fiddle, so I'm not so sure how to do it right: https://jsfiddle.net/3xrhmoas/

Comment: Have you got the solution already?

Comment: Solved it, thanks! DigitalDouble had the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    height: 51px;
}
```

The `51px` height is limiting your collapsible nav to show entirely.

** *Not related to your question* **

When using Bootstrap don't use `row` outside a `container` div since it will cause unnecessary horizontal scrollbars to appear.

Check your HTML for this element: `#home #banner .centered .row`. It's showing a scrollbar on my browser.